# Constuctor with database name argument

Tags: java, android

I wanna create constructor for DatabaseOpenHelper, that take argument for database name. I tried do something like this:

```
    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String DB_NAME){
        this.DB_NAME = DB_NAME; //There is error
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        APP_DATA_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

but I'm getting error, because `super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);` must be before `this.DB_NAME = DB_NAME;`
So is there any way how to create constuctor where I can specify what database I want to open in object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String DB_NAME){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.DB_NAME = DB_NAME; 
        APP_DATA_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Because eventually, you're passing the same `DB_NAME` variable to super constructor regardless of where you position it in the constructor.

You just have to call the constructor with your required name:

```
new DatabaseOpenHelper(this,"mydb1");
new DatabaseOpenHelper(this,"mydb2");
```